# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' when writing into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to scrape (using a loop for different users) from a website and then saving it in a dictionary and writing it in a file.

The problem is users are in hundreds and not every user has same data in json. For the users which don't have a particular set of rows of data it gives me that error.

```
for i in range(10):
    u = User(list_of_users[i])

    try:
        data_list = [[u.name, u.full_name, u.date_of_birth
    ,u.current_age, p.job_info.get('UserId').get('JobId'), p.job_info_with_z.get('UserId').get('location')]]

    except AttributeError:
        data_list = [[u.name, u.full_name, u.date_of_birth
    ,u.current_age, p.job_info.get('UserId').get('JobId'), p.job_info_with_z.get('UserId').get('location')]]
    with open('test_players_data.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(data_list)
```

.name calls a method to get the name, like wise for job_info and info_with_z.

so this works for majority of the users but for users who don't have "UserId" it gives me the above error. But there are some users who will have UserId but not UserIdWithZ. I want to skip those with some default value and keep on scraping data and write it in the file. Once it fails, it doesn't go forward.

There has to be a way to give default values where keys are not present. I have trimmed data. So every user has more than 30 different values that I am trying to scrape in 4 blocks of code.

example data

```
{
'UserId':  {'jobId': '74', 'jobLocation': '72', 'jobType': '10'},
'UserIdWithZ: {'jobId': '74', 'jobLocation': '72', 'jobType': '10'}
}
```

I just want that row/record in .csv to populate '' or '-' or 'na' where there isn't any data and not just fail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Specify the default value using `.get` so in your case,

```
p.job_info.get('UserId', {}).get('JobId', '-')
```

If you are expecting a `dict` to chain the next `get` you need to specify the default value as `{}`. If there aint no value for `job_info.get('UserId')`, `None` will be the default value, which doesnt have `get` method.

Do the same for all the `.get` methods,

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this. it works for the first key but nothing after that. what I mean is that it works for if the key is not found in the above e.g. that would be UserId. but it doesn't work when I default that UserId to '-' and then try to navigate inside '-' { '-'}

Comment: you can use `get` method on `None`. If you are expecting to use a `dict` make sure you are providing one.